# Limitar valores exibidos em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como eu faço para "limitar a quantidade dos valores ordenados pelo for abaixo?

Tentei criar um array com os Divs e trocar a propriedade display.. porém ele não pega a ordem dos elementos..

Grande parte deste código foi retirado de um tópico anterior.

```
// Seleciona as divs que queremos ordenar
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#res .alqb');

// Converte a NodeList de divs para array

var ordem = [].map.call(divs, function(element) {
    return element;

});

// Ordena a array pelo atributo 'value'
ordem.sort(function(a,b) {
    var ca = parseInt(a.getAttribute('value'), 10);
    var cb = parseInt(b.getAttribute('value'), 10);
    return cb - ca;
});


// Reinsere os filhos no pai, resultando na ordem desejada
var container = document.querySelector('#res');
for(var i=0; i<ordem.length; i++) {
    container.appendChild(ordem[i]); 
}  
trocacorresp();
qtdjogo();
}
```

Comment: Olá Vitor, podes explicar melhor a pergunta? talvez com um exemplo do que queres fazer?

Comment: O código acima retorna por ordem de tamanho do maior para o menor  alguns números que repetem mais vezes em  um determinado intervalo gostaria de fazer como se fosse um "filtro"  dos 6 primeiros.. ou seja os seis maiores valores...

Comment: Testa juntar `.slice(0, 6)` para ficar assim: `ordem.sort(..etc..).slice(0, 6);`. É isso que procuras?